# Reshaping a list containing an array in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to reshape the list `Ii` to `(1,11,2)` but I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

Ii=[np.array([[0, 2],
        [2, 4],
        [2, 5],
        [2, 6],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 7],
        [4, 5],
        [4, 6],
        [5, 3],
        [5, 7],
        [6, 5]])]

Y=Ii[0].shape
Ii=Ii[0].reshape(1,Y)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    Ii=Ii[0].reshape(1,Y)

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The expected output is

```
array([[[0, 2],
        [2, 4],
        [2, 5],
        [2, 6],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 7],
        [4, 5],
        [4, 6],
        [5, 3],
        [5, 7],
        [6, 5]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) can be used here to reshape the array.

```
Ii[0][np.newaxis,:]
```

or you can use [`reshaping`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) after [`unpacking`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) tuple.

```
Ii[0].reshape([1, *Y])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Ii = Ii[0].reshape(1, Y[0], Y[1])
```

Comment: This would only work if array to be reshaped is 2D.